# Inconsistency when Applying Gauss' Law

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, conductors

I'm using two methods to calculate the net electric field a certain distance away from the conductor. In the first method, I let the Gaussian cylinder go completely through the conductor and did the following calculations. For the second scenario, I imagined two distinct gaussian cylinders, with one face in the conductor for both sides (where the electric field is zero).I'm having trouble understanding why it is that when I split my Gaussian Cylinder in half and consider two gaussian cylinders in a conductor, when I add them up, they give a different answer than if I were to just consider one gaussian cylinder.

Am I encountering a conceptual misunderstanding? I believe the calculations are correct so that would be the only possible reason...

[image]

Comment: What you have called $\int E$ in the first scenario is the flux through one end of the cylinder, not through both of them, so you should not add them in the second scenario.

Comment: I accounted for two fluxes though, but just put a coefficient of 2 because they are equal in the first scenario if I'm measuring at equidistant points.

Comment: In method 2 it is you final addition which is incorrect. In method 2 you have assumed that the flux through the surface inside the conductor is zero because the electric field in the conductor is zero and yet when you do the addition you have assumed there is an electric field going through the conductor and that surface.

Comment: For a conductor, wouldn't the left side of the charged slab also contribute to the electric field to the right side of the slab? I was taught that both surfaces contribute to the left and right sides.

Answer (score 0):

My earlier answer did not look correctly at your work.

There is no reason to add the field from the second gaussian cylinder.  The field at the surface of the cylinder depends only on the flux through that cylinder.  The incorrect bit is the last step, which is unnecessary.  The presence of the second plate is inferred by the fact that the field is zero at the left-hand surface of the first cylinder.

Comment: I believe I accounted for the factor of 2 however, in the denominator? Normally for charges focused on a infinitely large surface, the electric field is sigma/epsilon. But in this case I accounted for the factor of 2, no?